# Run docker-compose on remote host with alternate ssh key

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, docker-compose, ssh-keys

I would like to deploy a set of docker containers on a remote docker host using `docker-compose -H ssh://user@host up`

This works fine as I added my default public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the remote hosts *authorized_keys*

But how can I specify an alternative private key? Is there an option like when using ssh: `ssh -i /path/to/key user@host` ?

Background: I would like to trigger a `docker-compose` deployment on a remote Host using Jenkins. I created a Jenkins Credential of the Kind "SSH Username with private key". Using the credentials plugin I can also get a hold of the key using something like

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'some.id', keyFileVariable: 'PKEY')]) {
    // $PKEY points to temp. available key file
}
```

But I don't know how I could pass that to `docker-compose -H ...`

Or is there a way not to use a key and prompt for the password with a similar mechanism as in `docker login --password-stdin`?